# Ember REST Adapter, change record before save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

*Main question*:

**Is there something like a `willSave` or `beforeSave` or `beforeCreateRecord`or `didCreate` method for Ember Data RESTAdapter?**

*Background*:

I have a have some data which requires me to make an *extra* API call, and use the results of that call, before every `createRecord`.

The problem is, if I try to override `createRecord`, the `DS.Snapshot` therein doesn't allow me to change its properties before it gets saved.

Ideally I'd like to make this call *before* `createRecord` but I am open to *after* `createRecord` as well.

It also needs to be adapter method as far as I can tell, *not* a model hook, because there is a native object I need access to which I don't want to save on the server. (i.e. `DS.Model`'s `didCreate` returns the already-stored data from the server)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should count on being able to do something before `createRecord` since we're encouraged to use it directly if we want to push data onto the store. For example if you want to create a record inside of an action you would do:

```
this.store.createRecord('bank', {
  name: this.get('bankForm.name'),
  image: this.get('bankForm.image')
});
```

You can however override the RESTSerializers `serialize` method that gets called on save to prepare the object to be sent. Then you can change the data to whatever is appropriate to your use case. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_customizing-an-app-wide-serializer

There's of course an equivalent `normalize` method to override if you're looking at adding something to the object post-save. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize

Comment: thanks Kit!  I think `serialize` will work because instead of returning a `DS.Snapshot`, which I can't modify, it returns JSON, which I can modify.  I will implement soon to check!

Comment: ok so I finally did this, BUT the problem is that `serialize` breaks when I return a promise!  it will only accept JSON therefore I can't even make my async request first.....